# Derivative of $f(x)=\int_1^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{\text{d}t}{\sqrt{(t^2-1)(1-t^2x^2)}}$

Tags: analysis

This function:

$$f(x)=\int_1^{\frac{1}{x}}\frac{\text{d}t}{\sqrt{(t^2-1)(1-t^2x^2)}}$$ where $x\in (0,1)$

I want to find its derivative.

In order to solve this question. I go back to general cases: $$f(x)=\int_a^{\varphi(x)}F(x,t)\text{d}t$$
By definition: $$f'(x)=\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$$

$$=\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\int_a^{\varphi(x+\Delta x)}F(x+\Delta x,t)\text{d}t-\int_a^{\varphi(x)}F(x,t)\text{d}t}{\Delta x}=$$ 
$$\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\Delta x}\int_a^{\varphi(x+\Delta x)}[F(x+\Delta x,t)-F(x,t)]\text{d}t + \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\Delta x} \int_{\varphi(x)}^{\varphi(x+\Delta x)}F(x,t)\text{d}t=$$
$$\int_a^{\varphi(x)}\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x,t)\text{d}t+\varphi'(x)F(x,\varphi(x))$$

But I use this to the function mentioned in the beginning. there are something wrong:

because $F(x,\varphi(x))$ is meaningless.

Does this function have derivatives ? How to find it?

Comment: Do you mean for the integrand to be complex-valued?  (Because it is for values of $t<1$).

Comment: Why is it meaningless ?

Comment: See the [Leibniz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) about [differentiating under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Comment: In order for the elliptic integral to be real-valued, the elliptic modulus $x$  needs to be restricted  $|x|<1$. So the function you've defined will only be real-valued on the domain where both $x$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ have magnitude less than one. You see the problem?

Comment: @JPi, sorry .I made a mistake. the integral is from $1$,not $0$

Comment: @DavidH I have edited the post. the integral lower bound is $1$, and $x \in (0,1)$. then the integral is real-valued.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus because $\varphi(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. then $F(x,\varphi(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\frac{1}{x^2})(1-1)}}$ so it is meaningless

Answer (score 2):

It is an elliptic integral of the first kind. The derivative is expressed in terms of elliptic integrals of the first and second kind.

[image]